# Best way to partially deep copy a dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, copy, deep-copy

I have a graph that is represented as a `dict` where each key is an instance of a (self-defined) `Node` class and the values are sets of instances of `Nodes`. So, basically, the graph looks something like this, but way larger:

`g = { Node1 : {Node2, Node3}, Node2 : {Node4}, Node3: set(), Node4 : {Node1} }`

**In very short words of what I want to do:** I want to arbitrarily change a dictionary and then revert it to its original value before those changes.

I have a series of transformations that I can make to this graph, but I don't have any possible way of knowing beforehand which transformation that I want to do. The transformation will always:

- Delete one key
- Add in two new vertices
- Change about 1/n edges

Since I don't know which transformation I want to do, I want to perform every transformation to the same graph and then pick one.

An obvious idiom could be:

- Copy the dictionary to a temporary dictionary (`temp = g`)
- Repeat for each transformation `t`:

  - Perform a transformation `t` on the graph `g` to form the graph `g'`
  - Jot down information about the graph `g'` for later
  - Set `g = temp` to restore the graph to the known-good state

This does not work because copying the dictionary only performs a shallow copy, so all changes to `g` are also performed on `temp`.

I can use `deepcopy`, but even that cannot work as is. I want to `deepcopy` the actual dictionary `g`, but the keys and elements in the values of `g` (the `Nodes`) cannot be deepcopied, because in my transformation, I will look for elements that are in `g` but not in `temp` because they are now new objects.

I can attempt to redefine `deepcopy` for the `Node` class, which *works*, but it is very hackish and I *do* need to use deepcopy to perform my transformations `t`.

Following is a minimal working example that does what I want it to do -- but in a way that I *do not want to* because then I need to create a workaround for making deepcopy actually work when I need it to. Also, the code to do the transformations is all using `g` and the actual `Nodes` in `g` as it stands right now, so not having to change much of that would be nice.

Is there a better way to do this? (all `print`s should be `True`)

```
from copy import deepcopy

class MyClass:

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.value)

    def __deepcopy__(self, memo):
    # do not rly deep copy plx
        return self

    class1 = MyClass(1)
    class2 = MyClass(2)
    class3 = MyClass(3)

    dict_class = { class1 : {class2, class3}, class2 : {class3}, class3 : {class1}}

    #### Want to create a copy of the dictionary with exact same objects... ####

    dict_class_copy = deepcopy(dict_class)

    print(dict_class)
    print(dict_class_copy)

    print(class1 in dict_class and class2 in dict_class and class3 in dict_class)
    print(class1 in dict_class_copy and class2 in dict_class_copy and class3 in dict_class_copy)

    dict_class.pop(class2)
    dict_class[class1].remove(class3)

    # don't want to change original dictionary key values
    print(class2 not in dict_class and class2 in dict_class_copy)

    # this breaks w/o deepcopy!
    print(class3 not in dict_class[class1] and class3 in dict_class_copy[class1])

    # reassign it back 
    dict_class = dict_class_copy 

    # i want this back!
    print(class2 in dict_class)
    print(class3 in dict_class[class1])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a "1 level deep" copy of the dict by copying the keys and making copies of the sets.  Replace this:

```
dict_class_copy = deepcopy(dict_class)
```

with this:

```
dict_class_copy = {k:set(v) for k,v in dict_class.items()}
```

and your tests pass.

Comment: I had to modify my code to continuously do this in my loop, but this definitely helped me. Thanks.